# Inference not giving the same result as the model did after training

Tags: pytorch, inference

I have trained a model on a deep fashion dataset and now I am doing inference. The thing is that I am not getting the full result like I got when I tested the model after I trained it. Here are the pkl and pth [files](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1i-N0Jy9xBJfYNZlr17ewcCniv5U9qplg?usp=sharing)

This is my inference script

```
import torch
import torchvision.models as models
from torchvision import transforms
from torch.autograd import Variable
from PIL import Image
import torch.nn as nn



MODEL_PATH = "/content/deepfashion-dataset/models/atr-recognition-stage-2-resnet34.pkl"
DATA_PATH = "/content/deepfashion-dataset/"
CLASSES_PATH = "/content/deepfashion-dataset/clothes_categories/attribute-classes.txt"


class ClassificationModel():
    
    def __init__(self):
        return
        
    def load(self, model_path, labels_path,  eval=False):
        self.model = torch.load(model_path)
        self.model = nn.Sequential(self.model)
        
        self.labels = open(labels_path, 'r').read().splitlines()
        
        if eval:
            print(model.eval())
        return
    
    def predict(self, image_path):
        
        device = torch.device("cpu")
        img = Image.open(image_path)
        
        test_transforms = transforms.Compose([transforms.Resize(224),
                                      transforms.ToTensor(),
                                      transforms.Normalize([0.485, 0.456, 0.406],
                                                           [0.229, 0.224, 0.225])
                                     ])
        
        image_tensor = test_transforms(img).float()
        image_tensor = image_tensor.unsqueeze_(0)
        inp = Variable(image_tensor)
        inp = inp.to(device)
        output = self.model(inp)
        index = output.data.cpu().numpy().argmax()
        return self.labels[index]

learner = ClassificationModel()
learner.load(MODEL_PATH, CLASSES_PATH)
print(learner.predict(DATA_PATH+"img-lk/IMG_20210530_152109_062.jpg"))
```

The output it gives for this image is:

```
leather
```

While when I tested it after training the model like this:

```
def predict_attribute(model, path, display_img=True):
    predicted = model.predict(path)
    if display_img:
        size = 244,244
        img=Image.open(path)
        img.thumbnail(size,Image.ANTIALIAS)
        display(img)
    return predicted[0]

image_path = PATH + 'img-lk/IMG_20210530_152109_062.jpg'
predict_attribute(learn, image_path)
```

Output was:

```
(#2) ['faux-leather','leather']
```

It gave both the output attributes that time. Also my attributes are saved in a text [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1iuFKvMhe8t2aQhoK0wi3YuWrVgWMEh9Q/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: Could you provide your model definition?

Comment: @Ivan It's a model that tells about the cloth attributes like material, design, etc. For example, by giving it a picture of a dress, it can identify that it is (animal printed, chiffon) etc